# Running "operating system updates" in appcenter of Elementary gets cancelled

Tags: updates, system, appcenter

I have a problem with updating my Elementary OS system.

When I click on the button "update" of the "operating system updates" in the appcenter of Elementary os, the update gets "cancelled".
[image: Updating system updates]

If I try a second time, it gets cancelled too and I get this strange situation.
[image: After updating system updates second time]

Then if I try to update in the terminal, I get the message that there are some dependencies not ok.

`peter@peter-DP505-DM515:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libperl5.22 : Breaks: libperl5.22:i386 (!= 5.22.1-9) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 is installed
 libperl5.22:i386 : Breaks: libperl5.22 (!= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2) but 5.22.1-9 is installed
 perl : Depends: libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2) but 5.22.1-9 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
peter@peter-DP505-DM515:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libperl5.22
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3391 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12,3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 304486 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libperl5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2) over (5.22.1-9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libperl5.22/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libperl5.22:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
peter@peter-DP505-DM515:~$`

Do I have to uninstall something, delete something or install a newer version of an item that is not monitored by the appcenter to be able to get my updates again?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the terminal. libperl5.22 is the only package I am unable to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/+bug/1574351):

```
sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libperl5.22/changelog.Debian.gz
sudo apt install -f
```

I hope this fixes it for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today not elementaryOS, but on Ubuntu 16.04, also with amd64 as a foreign architecture.  There seems to be a conflict between the two architectures which I don't think should happen.

I just deleted `/usr/share/doc/libperl5.22/changelog.Debian.gz` and re-ran `apt full-upgrade -f`.